# variable in function nor returning values after else statement

Tags: python

Im new with Python and my function is not working as expected. Im trying to save some values in a list list_alt[i] but if i call the values outside the if or else statements i get only None.

```
import os.path
import xlrd
import sys
import argparse

def readExcel():
     workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
     sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
     sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
     j=0
     for row in range(sheet.nrows):
          j += 1
     rownumber=j
     print (rownumber)

     k=0
     i=0
     list_alt=[None]*j 
     list_neu=[None]*j
     while (i<j-10):
          #get first row values
          temp = sheet.cell_value(k,0).replace('www.website.com/','')   
          #get second row values
          temp2 = sheet.cell_value(k,1)
          if "http:" in temp2:
               temp2 = sheet.cell_value(k,1).replace('http:','https:')
               list_neu[i]=temp2
               list_alt[i]=temp
               k+=0
               i+=1
          else:
               list_neu[i]=temp2
               list_alt[i]=temp
               #i can print the values here
               print (list_alt[i])
               print (list_neu[i]) 
               i+=1
               k+=1

          #I cant print for the values here anymore
          print (list_alt[i])
          print (list_neu[i])
          print (i)

     return list_alt, list_neu
```

Comment: Indentation matters very much in Python. Please format your code to reflect the actual indentation you have.

Comment: I updated the code to reflect the actual indentation. It is actualy in the "else" statement where i can print my values but outside it the list is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got `IndexError`, It should be caused by `i` is increased before use by indexing `list_alt[i]`.

```
import os.path
import xlrd
import sys
import argparse

def readExcel():
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
j=0
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    j += 1
rownumber=j
print (rownumber)

k=0
i=0
list_alt=[None]*j 
list_neu=[None]*j
while (i<j-10):
    temp = sheet.cell_value(k,0).replace('www.website.com/','') 
    temp2 = sheet.cell_value(k,1)
    if "http:" in temp2:
        temp2 = sheet.cell_value(k,1).replace('http:','https:')
        list_neu[i]=temp2
        list_alt[i]=temp
        k+=0
        # variable i is increased.
        i+=1
    elif "http" not in temp2:
        print ("not there")
        k+=1
    else:
        list_neu[i]=temp2
        list_alt[i]=temp
        print (list_alt[i])
        print (list_neu[i]) 
        # variable i is increased.
        i+=1
        k+=1

    # variable i is increased before.
    # you may purpose to read list_alt[i-1].
    print (list_alt[i])
    print (i)

return list_alt, list_neu
```

I do hope my answer is helpful. :D

Answer (score 1):

The lines past `if/else` are executed *after* `i` has been incremented, so of course it will print `None`, since that is indeed the value of `list_alt[i]`. Your function should be returning the proper values, regardless. If you'd like to see the value you just inserted consider two possible changes:

1. increment `i` as the last line within the while loop
2. `print(list_alt[i-1])` instead